# Implementation of lazy filter in clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

On http://clojure.org/lazy, `filter` is defined this way:

```
(defn filter
  "Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which
  (pred item) returns true. pred must be free of side-effects."
  [pred coll]
  (let [step (fn [p c]
                 (when-let [s (seq c)]
                   (if (p (first s))
                     (cons (first s) (filter p (rest s)))
                     (recur p (rest s)))))]
    (lazy-seq (step pred coll))))
```

Is it important that the recursive call is to `filter`, not to `step`? If it is, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is with the rest of the code as given here, because it is `filter` which does the wrapping in `lazy-seq`. If `step` called itself, it would do all the filtering at once instead of lazily.

*(Updated.)* If `lazy-seq` was added to `step`'s body, `step` could then call itself and still be lazy. This could be accomplished at least in these two ways:

1. by wrapping the entire body in `lazy-seq` and replacing both the recursive call to `filter` and the `recur` with calls to `step`; NB. in this case the `step` function would need to be named (either by replacing the `let` with `letfn`, with the appropriate change in syntax, or by adding a name to the `fn` form: `(fn step ...)`); the `lazy-seq` wrapping the outermost call to `step` would then be unnecessary; also, at this point you could simply not have an inner helper function (just use this approach in `filter` directly);
2. by leaving the `lazy-seq` in `filter` in place and wrapping the recursive call in `step` (which would now be to `step` itself) in `lazy-seq` (with the `recur` form remaining unchanged).

Note that `clojure.core/filter` has a different implementation, with separate logic handling chunked sequences and no internal helper functions. In the non-chunked case it operates like the version of `step` described in 1. above.

Comment: But if i wrap the whole body with `lazy-seq`, then `recur` wouldn't be in tail position

Comment: @tempestadept Right, you'd have to replace it with another recursive call. (`clojure.core/filter` effectively operates like that in the non-chunked case.) I've edited the answer to take this into account.